# Data re-structuring by Thread

Tags: list-manipulation, data-structures

`Thread` can do this

```
Thread[{a, {b, c, d}}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}}
> ```

But when above `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are themselves `List`s, for instance, used as a representation for 2D/3D points, it will not work as a naive generalization

```
Thread[{{a, b}, {{x, y}, {z, w}, {u, v}}}]
```

which just raises an error.

Here what is intended for is

```
{{{a, b}, {x, y}}, {{a, b}, {z, w}}, {{a, b}, {u, v}}}
```

So can it still be realized by `Thread`? If yes, how? If no, then do there exist any concise and efficient workarounds?

Comment: An interesting question.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A level specification can help (we have to specify the head to thread over, too):

```
Thread[{{a, b}, {{x, y}, {z, w}, {u, v}}}, List, {2}]
```

> {{{a, b}, {x, y}}, {{a, b}, {z, w}}, {{a, b}, {u, v}}}

Note that this [unpacks arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496), so I would not suggest that for big datasets. I that case, I would propose a `ConstantArray`/`Transpose` combo:

```
n = 1000000 ;
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2];
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];

Thread[{a, b}, List, {2}] // Developer`PackedArrayQ // AbsoluteTiming

Transpose[{ConstantArray[a, n],b}] // Developer`PackedArrayQ // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.347755, False}
>
> {0.046035, True}

Comment: It seems it. So any clarification for the curly brackets around `2` here? The F1 documentation of `Thread` does not mention level specification.

Comment: For level specifications, `f[...,n]` with integer `n` usually means "until level `n`" while `f[...,{n}]` means "only at level `n`".

Comment: Sorry, do you mean `f[..., {n}]` in the latter?

Comment: Yes. But I fixed the comment already. Thanks for the accept btw.

Comment: Your information on packed array is valuable.